# LinQ with multiple joins, left join with where clause, and group by

Tags: linq, group-by, left-join, where-clause

Hihi all, after googling around for hours, still stuck with my linq statement.

I have 3 tables:

```
- tblRequest : RequestID, RequestDate, UserID
- tblUser: UserID, Username
- tbMessage: MessageID, RequestID, IsRead
```

*RequestID in tbMessage is a foreign key of RequestID in tblRequest*

My scenario is that, I need to get all requests from tblRequest for on particular user, with the count of unread messages.

The selected fields should be tblRequest.RequestID, tblRequest.RequsetDate, tblUser.Username, COUNTOfUnreadMessage (Isread == false)

Thanks in advance!

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DBContext relationships:

```
from r in db.Requests
where r.UserID == _userID
select new
{
  r.RequestId,
  r.RequestDate,
  r.User.Username,
  UnreadMessagesCount = r.Messages.Where(m=>!m.IsRead).Count()
}
```

Where _userID is a local variable with the desired user id.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution for you. db is the linq database context. Hope this helps

```
var userId=1;
    (
        from req in db.tblRequest
        join user in db.tblUser
            on req.UserID equals user.UserID
        where 
            req.UserID==userId
        select new
        {
            req.RequestID,
            req.RequestDate,
            user.Username,
            COUNTOfUnreadMessage= db.tbMessage.Where(a=>a.RequestID==req.RequestID && a.IsRead==false).Count()
        }
    ).ToList()
```